# Style does not apply when is_approved equals 0

Tags: php

I have a table "pharma_companies" in that, there is a column name called "is_approved".  I want to apply a stylesheet if is_approved column contains 0 value

```
 <select name="current_company" id="current_company" class="validate[required]">
             <option value="">Select Company</option>
           <?php
               $current_sql = "SELECT pharma_companies FROM pharma_companies ORDER BY pharma_companies";
               $currenex = mysqli_query($db,$current_sql);

              while($pharama = mysqli_fetch_assoc($currenex))
              {
                   if($pharama['is_approved'] == '0')
                   {                                                
                       $style = 'style = "color:red;"';
                   }
                   else
                   {                                                
                       $style = '';
                   }



                  echo '<option value="'.$pharama['pharma_companies'].'" '.$style.'>'.$pharama['pharma_companies'].'</option>';
              }
          ?>
       </select>
```

but it does not work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show the html that gets printed?

Comment: change == '0' to == NULL

Comment: could it be that all of them are approved?

Comment: I have one data which is have 0 in is_approved coloum but it does not apply in select box

Comment: you want to select only 'pharma_companies' field not select 'is_approved' field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are actually never grabbing the `is_approved` column from the database.

Change your SQL to:

```
$current_sql = "SELECT pharma_companies, is_approved FROM pharma_companies ORDER BY pharma_companies";
```

Answer (score 0):

1) First thing you need to fetch is_approved fiedl

```
$current_sql = "SELECT pharma_companies, is_approved FROM pharma_companies ORDER BY pharma_companies";
```

2) try condition as

```
if($pharama['is_approved'] == '0' || $pharama['is_approved']==0 )
```